# Getting image path in public folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making direction using this method to upload my image

```
 mkdir(public_path().'/website/'.$path,0777, true);
```

It's supposed to create it on the root folder (Public_html) , but i found it created on new folder with name (public ) , so now i can't get the path of the image using this code

```
 <img src="{{url('public/website/'.$file->path.$file->file)}}"  />
```

how to get the correct path of the image or even create the folder on the public_html root path ?

Comment: Try <img src="{{asset('website/'.$file->path.$file->file)}}" />

Comment: use base_path() instead of public_path()

Comment: It back with that url for image [link]http://www.premiumcaregold.com/public/website/images/1490866162/78881490866162.jpg[link] ,

Comment: It's create the image on this path ( public /website/images/foldername/imagename.path )
It's backing with this path on showPage
http://www.premiumcaregold.com/public/website/images/1490866162/78881490866162.jpg
It's suppose to be right path but it's not showing to me !

Comment: What's code you use to upload image?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this to get image**

```
 <img src="<?php echo public_path().'/website/'.$path.$file->file;  ?>"  />
```

Comment: Look the images is at this path :  publicfolder/websitefolder/images/img.jpg
It's can't see the public folder , it's only see the public_html folder ! 
so how to get the path from it ?

Comment: would you define your HTTP_ROOT in controller.php

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use public_path(); function in laravel 
or
<img src="{{ public_path().'/website/'.$file->path.'/'.$file->file;}}"  />
or
<img src="/website/{{$file->path.$file->file}}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You try this to get your image content**

```
  <img src="<?php echo asset('/').'public/'.$path.$file->file;  ?>"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

[See Here for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset)

You can use laravel helper function asset 
for eg. $url = asset('img/photo.jpg'); then you will get full path with public directory. $url return www.your.domain.com/public/img/photo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it but... did you have tried this way?

```
mkdir(public_path('/website/'.$path),0777, true);
```

To me, if I'm not wrong your problem could be only a matter of writing.